# Difference between wget and browser file downloading

Tags: wget

I have a direct link http://oocairo.naquadah.org/dist/oocairo-1.4.tar.bz2

And it's downloading fine throught chromium web browser. But throught `wget`

```
$ wget http://oocairo.naquadah.org/dist/oocairo-1.4.tar.bz2
--2012-05-07 18:44:44--  http://oocairo.naquadah.org/dist/oocairo-1.4.tar.bz2
Parsing oocairo.naquadah.org... 2a02:2178:2:4::174, 212.85.154.174
Connecting to oocairo.naquadah.org|2a02:2178:2:4::174|:80...
```

it's just hang. Why?

Comment: Have you tried `wget --user-agent="Chrome 9.5 Gecko 1.7" http://...` already?

Comment: post that as an answer

Comment: I can't do it, while my reputation is less than 100.

Comment: @Lescott you should be able to do it now since 8 hours have passed by

Comment: Done. (And some more text to overcome comment lenght limit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in IPv6 using. 
`wget -4 http://oocairo.naquadah.org/dist/oocairo-1.4.tar.bz2` is working fine.